# Docker container cannot be accessed via ‘docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash'

Tags: java, docker

Today, following error occurred for a java process inside a docker container :

```
test-service-register | 2020-02-27 16:14:56.398 ERROR [test-service-register,,,] 9 --- [nio-8204-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread] with root cause
test-service-register | java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
test-service-register |         at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_202]
test-service-register |         at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717) [na:1.8.0_202]
test-service-register |         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957) [na:1.8.0_202]
test-service-register |         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1367) [na:1.8.0_202]
test-service-register |         at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
test-service-register |         at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextScheduler$ThreadPoolWorker.schedule(HystrixContextScheduler.java:172) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
test-service-register |         at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextScheduler$HystrixContextSchedulerWorker.schedule(HystrixContextScheduler.java:106) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10352) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10319) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:410) ~[rxjava-1.3.6.jar!/:1.3.6]
test-service-register |         at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:378) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
test-service-register |         at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:344) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
test-service-register |         at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler.invoke(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:159) ~[feign-hystrix-9.5.1.jar!/:na]
```

And when I tried to enter the container, the following error occurred:
[image]

I have confirmed the memory status of the container as follow:
[image]

Also, I tried inquiry transaction, and the java process can return normally.
but when I tried a transaction which calls another service via feign by the java process, it ends up with above error:

> OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread.

Finally, after I restart the container, and everything goes back to normal...

I forgot to add `-XX:HeapDumpPath` parameter when the jvm started, and there is no dump file for analysis.

Can anybody please help to give me a hint on where the problem is? Appreciate your help very much.

Comment: How much memory does your container have (how much memory do you give to java?) ? Is the container still running after that error (I believe it should exit)?

Comment: Please replace those images with the actual text of the error you're getting.  They're oddly skewed and the actual error is cut off.

Comment: The container is still running after that error, because inquiry transaction can be processed normally. If container had exit, inquiry transaction should fail.  the java option is : JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -Xms1024m.